In a flet app I cannot access assets file, I receive a PathAccessException each time
I'm using/learning flet v0.23.2 and every time I access (in read mode) a file on the /assets directory (the path is correct and the directory exists) I get this error:
PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = 'mypath/assets/icon.png' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

This is my code:
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Images Example"
    page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.LIGHT
    page.padding = 50
    page.update()

    img = ft.Image(
        src=f"/assets/icon.png",
        width=100,
        height=100,
        fit=ft.ImageFit.CONTAIN,
    )
    images = ft.Row(expand=1, wrap=False, scroll="always")

    page.add(img, images)

    page.update()

ft.app(main)

I tried to run the app in these ways:
flet run myapp.py
flet run -a <path to assets> myapp.py

and I tried with the app call is in this way:
...
img = ft.Image(
        src=f"icon.png",
        width=100,
        height=100,
        fit=ft.ImageFit.CONTAIN,
    )
...
flet.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")

I'm using a MAC OS and the assets directory and files are readable.

I answer to my question: I upgraded flet and when I run an application it asked if it can access to my documents, I answered yes and it worked. I don't know how to change this info in a static way.

...
img = ft.Image(
        src=f"/icon.png",
        width=100,
        height=100,
        fit=ft.ImageFit.CONTAIN,
    )
...
flet.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")

I think if you just add the slash before your relative file paths it should be fixed.
